# Simple database editor

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am looking for a java based web application that can be deployed to a tomcat and a simple frontend that supports CRUD operations.
I know I can write my own but what I am looking for is something to auto generate the hole application:

- Entities
- repositories
- Simple frontend to perform CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can write my own but what I am looking for is something to
> auto generate the hole application

You are not going to find a tool that will auto generate your whole application without you having to write something.  There are tools that minimize the amount of code you have to write though.  For example, with Grails you could do this:

```
grails create-app myapp
cd myapp
grails create-domain-class demo.Person
grails generate-all demo.Person
```

Edit `grails-app/domain/demo/Person.groovy` to look like this (this is the only code you would have to write):

```
package demo

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

Now you can run the app with `./gradlew bootRun` and a fully functioning CRUD interface will be available at http://localhost:8080/person.

There is a whole lot more than just that which can be done with the app, but that is a very simple way to get a fully functioning CRUD web interface up and running.  That trivial app could literally be written in about 2 or 3 minutes.